# VB.NET Incrementing Indexes

Tags: vb.net, increment, indexing

I am having trouble incrementing the indexes of my list item properties. Here is the code.

```
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For x As Integer = 1 To list.Count / 19
            database.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES ('" + _
                                    list.Item(i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "', '" + _
                                    list.Item(++i) + "')")
        Next
```

The ++i does not increment at all in the parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use your loop variable (x) and increase the index in that manner.

I'm doing this in C# but I'm sure you will understand.

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO Contact VALUES ('";

for(int i = 1; i < list.Count ; i++)
{
   sql += list.Item(i) + "', '";

}
sql = sql.Remove(sql.Length -1);
sql += ")";

Database.ExecuteCommand(sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

VB.Net does not have an increment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Function

```
Function GetIncrementValue(ByRef x as Integer) as Integer
  x=x+1
  Return x
End function
```

Your Code will be......

```
Dim i As Integer = 0

For x As Integer = 1 To list.Count / 19
    database.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO Contacts VALUES ('" + _
                             list.Item(i) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "', '" + _
                             list.Item(GetIncrementValue(i)) + "')")
Next
```

Enjoy....